# A Hessian vs double gradient inequality.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

While watching a seminar on elliptic PDE's the presenter used the following inequality while claiming it is "standard".
$$|D^2u|\geq |\nabla|\nabla u||$$
I tried to prove this, but couldnt find a way. Can someone share a proof or a reference on this inequality.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, you can prove it just by squaring and expanding rather trivially. It will boil down to the following:
$$\sum_{i}f_i^2f_{ii}^2\leq \sum_i f_i^2 \sum_{i,j} f_{ij}^2$$
which is immediate after expanding and ignoring tons of non-negative terms.

Here, $f_i$ denotes partial derivatives and $f_{ij}$ is second-order cross partials and of course $f$ is assumed to be smooth so you cross partials are order independent and $$\|\cdot\|$$ is the Euclidean norm.